# MikroBasic, function of parentheses around number

Tags: microcontroller, pic, basic

```
if (conta1) and (15) = 15 then
    conta = conta - 6
end if
```

I don't understand the function of: `(15)`?

Comment: Hi! I think you should edit your post. Please put your snippet in correct tag and ask real question - there's nothing to answer.

Comment: At a guess, the author meant to write __(conta1 and 15) = 15__

Answer (score 0):

The mikroBasic "and" operator is a [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operation.

Decimal 15 is binary 0b00001111, the least significant four bits are set.  Bitwise anding a variable with decimal 15 effectively masks off everything except the least significant four bits of the value.  Then testing if that result is equal to 15 means you are testing whether the least significant bits are all set.

This if statement will be true if the least significant four bits of `conta1` are set.  The more significant bits are ignored and it doesn't matter whether they are set or not.